# help with linq query

Tags: linq

i am trying to get some data, but i dont know how can i do a if in linq, this is how i am trying to do

```
from so in db.Operations
where ((opType!= "0" ? so.Operation == int.Parse(opType) : false) 
    && (idState!=0 ? so.State == idState : false) 
    && (start != null ? so.StartDate == start : false) 
    && (end !=null ? so.EndDate == end : false))
select so
```

the optype is a Int, 
the idState is a Int,
end is a datetime,
start is a datime

what i am trying to do is, if those aren't null they add to the query function, so i can get all data together

for example: in c# code

```
if((opType!= "0")
 where (so.Operation == int.Parse(opType)
if(idState!=0)
 where (so.Operation == int.Parse(opType) && so.State == idState
.......
```

so if that isn't null, that sentence in that sql query (the TRUE part, i dont want to use the false part), add it to the where, so i can search all parameters that aren't null or 0

Comment: Can you describe what you want to do exactly. And also add some information what you want to get back. Currently only if all of the elements (optype, idState, end, and start) are set (i.e. do not contain their default values) and all conditions are met too a result is returned.

Comment: @Luis - If the values are null you want to ignore them and return data without restriction?  Or do you want the query to return nothing if any of those are null?

Comment: hi, what i can is if the variables are null dont add to where sentence, if isn't null add that to where sentece, for example

if(opType!=0) <br />
where so.operation == int.parse(optype) <br />
if(start!= null) <br />
where so.start == start && so.operation == int.parse(optype)...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well not sure what you want exactly but here is a try:

```
var query = db.Operations.AsQueryable();

if (opType != null && opType != "0")
    query = query.Where(x => x.Operation == int.Parse(opType);

if (idState != 0) 
    query = query.Where(x => x.State == idState);

if (start != null) // assuming that start is of type DateTime? otherwise use DateTime.MinValue
    query = query.Where(x => x.StartDate.Date == start); // maybe >= is more appropriate

if (end != null) // also DateTime? assumed
    query = query.Where(x => x.EndDate.Date == end); // maybe <= is more appropriate

var result = query.ToList(); // e.g. could also do an foreach, depending what you want to do
```

The trick in this approach is to build up the query successively. The query will not be enumerated until `.ToList()` or `foreach` is used to enumerate the list.

Actually this should yield the same:

```
from so in db.Operations
where ((opType != null && opType!= "0" ? so.Operation == int.Parse(opType) : true) 
    && (idState!=0 ? so.State == idState : true) 
    && (start != null ? so.StartDate.Date == start : true) 
    && (end !=null ? so.EndDate.Date == end : true))
select so
```

Comment: Timing issue, my answer is similar to yours, will delete mine.

Comment: No, see the edit ... the query is executed when, e.g. `.ToList()` is called. The concept used here is "deferred execution".

Comment: If you are happy you can accept the solution ... if not comment I'll try again.

Comment: now with the firs one, its ok, i changed var to iqueryable<...> and its ok, but now, it dont show any record :S, i looking for why.

Comment: Well, without knowing your data it is not really possible to help you there, sorry. Maybe opening another question with the data, and the result you want to achieve can help you there.

Comment: i think is the date... because in the DB have hour, how can i choose only the date in the x.Start or x.End ???
i already tried x.Start.Value.ToShortDateString == start.ToShotDateString... but gives the error, operator == cannot be applied to operadord of type method and method group

Comment: solved :D

 thanks a lot for the help obalix :), did it with x.Start.Value.year== start.year && x.Start.Value.month== start.month && x.Start.Value.day== start.day

Comment: edit again so i can rank it :P, dont know why it cames to zero, and ask to be edit again

Answer (score 1):

Since you're `&&`'ing them, looks like you want `: true` instead of `: false`.

Comment: i want the && because i want to add, if the variables aren't null, so it can search with all parameters that aren't null

Comment: @Luis: Right, but I mean, if it -is- null, you don't want to `&& false`, because that will always return an empty set.  So you should keep the &&'s, but replace your `: false`'s with `: true`'s.

Answer (score 0):

```
opType!= "0" ? so.Operation == int.Parse(opType) : false
```

you should not use so.operation == int.parse....  instead use so.operation = int.Parse(opType)

Comment: that dont work, because i dont want to egualate .


i dont know if I explaine very well, but that False, i dont want to use, i only want to use the true part

Comment: Are you saying that you should use `so.operation = int.Parse(opType)`? This would be an assignment operation and does not make sense in a where query.

Comment: what i want to do is, for example
if(opType!=0)
   where so.operation == int.parse(optype)

//if isn't null add's it to where 
if(start!= null)
   where so.start == start && so.operation == int.parse(optype)....

so it can be search with all parameters

Answer (score 0):

You can use conditional parameters.

Change:

```
where ((opType!= "0" ? so.Operation == int.Parse(opType) : false)
```

To:

```
where ((opType!= "0" ? so.Operation == int.Parse(opType) : so.Operation == Operation)
```

and so on...